Adding GIF images or images is very laggy or provides errors
I never had these issues in the past (using BSE for years now), but in the last weeks I have massive problems adding GIF images or images into my answers. While images work (after waiting a loooong time in comparison to earlier times)—so now it takes sometimes 30 secs or longer or doesn't work at all what needed 2-3 secs before—my GIF images don't upload anymore.
This wasn't any problem a month ago...
Are there any server problems on SE site?
Or do only I have these problems?

Is BSE blender? There's a new upload endpoint being rolled out, and it may potentially be related to that

Possibly related.

Related for GIF error & SE Image Uploader: Uploading a .gif doesn't work on some SE sites

Also posted on Meta.Blender.SE: New service failing on .gif uploads

thanks all for that informations!

Does this answer your question? Uploading a .gif doesn't work on some SE sites. I realise it doesn't give insight into the lag you experience, but that's another issue (even though possibly related), and requires a different thread.

@Joachim the lag is not 30 seconds but rather 3 seconds, compared to 1.5 seconds in the imgur upload, which is ending. But there is indeed a bug, the new upload process does not support gif images at this time, hopefully SE will fix it at some point.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda: sorry, cannot confirm that. it takes much longer than 3 seconds in my experience and it was much (!) faster before.
